# Why isn't DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader creating my classes?

Tags: perl, sql-server-2000, dbix-class

I am trying to generate static schemas using [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class) in Perl. The command shown below outputs a *Schema.pm* and no other files. Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or how to to debug this?

```
U:\wohlfarj\Software\PARS>perl -MDBIx::Class::Schema::Loader=make_schema_at,dump_to_dir:.\lib 
-e "make_schema_at('PARS::Schema',{debug=>1},['dbi:ODBC:PARS','user','password',{AutoCommit=>0}])"
Dumping manual schema for PARS::Schema to directory .\lib ...
Schema dump completed.
```

I'm using [Strawberry Perl](http://www.strawberryperl.com) on Windows XP. The database is SQL Server 2000, accessed through an ODBC connection. I can successfully run queries using plain old [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI) with the same ODBC connection.

Comment: I hand wrote the schema classes instead. That seems to work. There must be some problem getting the table definitions out of SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

try adding db_schema => "dbo" and odbc_exec_direct => 1, as in:

```
perl -MDBIx::Class::Schema::Loader=make_schema_at,dump_to_dir:.\lib -e "make_schema_at('PARS::Schema',{debug=>1, db_schema => "dbo"},['dbi:ODBC:PARS','user','password',{AutoCommit=>0, odbc_exec_direct => 1}])
```

Comment: need to upvote this one as it solves my problem similar to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that if there are any errors at all in the schema loading, make_schema_at will abort and not write anything at all. Ensure you diagnose any errors it outputs and try again.

In my case, I had debug=>1 set, which then outputs to terminal what it is doing, but it means you can't easily see if there are any errors in amongst all that output. Try setting debug=>0 to check for actual errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch that `.\lib` is not correct. Try again with `./lib` or just `lib`.

```
> perl -e'print ".\lib"' | hex
0000  2e 69 62                                          .ib
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried both *lib* and *./lib*. They had the same results - empty Schema.pm and no modules for the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to extract a schema (1200 tables!) from a Navision database. I ended up just using a "-o constraint" for the tables I wanted.